# Extjs Window Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I use Extjs 4.1 in bulding my web app. Since Viewport doesn't support `autoScroll: true`, I wanted to add this feature to my app so I tried: `Ext.getBody().setStyle('overflow', 'auto');` and it works, a scroll bars appear when i resize the browser, but the issue is any opened panel inside the app became completely white!

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Map', {
    extend: 'GeoExt.panel.Map',
    alias: 'widget.mymap',
    border: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        //for window scroll 
        Ext.getBody().setStyle('overflow', 'auto');
        Ext.apply(me, {
            map: map,
            height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);     
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the autoScroll: true in each and every panel or all the regions.So when browser resize it will get adjusted automatically.